# Does Android Studio support Kotlin method breakpoints?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, kotlin

I wasn't able to have the debugger hit method breakpoints unlike the case with Java.
As shown in the below image, Kotlin doesn't recognize method breakpoint.

[image: method breakpoint Kotlin vs Java]

Does Kotlin support method breakpoints? If yes how?

EDT
This issue is not reproduced on normal Intellij but on Android Studio 3.5.1

Comment: Yes it does. Remove the breakpoint and add it again, seems you added a different type of breakpoint

Comment: This has nothing to do with the language kotlin, it would have to do with the debugger you're using

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kotlin supports that. If it is not working, just restart the app, it will work or try to add breakpoint inside the function.